# Rails create action: Forbidden Attributes Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am new to rails and am in the process of entering in information in a form and saving it to a database. I am following a tutorial which may be out of date. I am getting an error on the second line. Am I passing the wrong parameter?

```
def create
    @student = Student.new(params[:student])
    if @student.save
        redirect_to new_student_path
    end
end
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add details about your `Student` model. Also, please add the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: Can you post what is inside `params[:student]`. You may be using a reserved value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect the problem is that you need to process the student parameters before passing them to `Student.new`, so as not to fall foul of the [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) system.

Try this:

```
def create
  @student = Student.new(student_parameters)
  if @student.save
    redirect_to new_student_path
  end
end

private

def student_parameters
  params.require(:student).permit(:name, :age)
end
```

replace `:name, :age` with the list of attributes you want to white list (allow through)

More information about the mass assignment vulnerability that strong parameters mitigates can be found [here](https://8thlight.com/blog/will-warner/2014/04/05/strong-parameters-in-rails.html).